# Native libraries not found in Tomcat

Tags: gwt, tomcat, java-native-interface

I developed an GWT application which includes some native libraries with JNI. when I test it from eclipse everything works fine, but when I try to deploy it on my Eclipse server it can't find the native libraries.

I followed [this tutorial for JNI and Tomcat](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/HowTo#I.27m_encountering_classloader_problems_when_using_JNI_under_Tomcat)

but it still can't find them I noticed. That when I read the  `java.library.path` from within my serversided application it is different from what I get when I start Tomcat (displaying the path variables with `set path`).

Any ideas what I am missing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add a native library in Tomcat?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14018817/how-to-add-a-native-library-in-tomcat)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest answer might be to edit your Tomcat installation's `bin/startup` script to change the `java.library.path` to wherever you're copying the native library to.  Something like

```
java -Djava.library.path=/path/to/my/libs existing args
```

If you're using a shared hosting provider, you'll need to consult with the owner to determine if they'll allow native libraries to be loaded into the container, and if there's a specific location to which the libraries should be copied.

Beyond that, there's the meta problem of your development environment being different from your deployment environment.  Ideally, you would have an exact copy (or as close as possible) of the deployment configuration running on your local development machine.

Answer (score 3):

I have struggled with that too. What finally worked for me was to put the JNI libraries in the `tomcat/shared/lib` directory and set the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable with the path to the JNI library. I also set the `JAVA_OPTS` environment variable to include the `-Djava.library.path` option.

Tomcat 7 by the way.

You will need to create the `shared/lib` directories if they do not exist.

On my Linux server this is how it is set:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/tomcat/shared/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.library.path=/usr/tomcat/shared/lib"
```