# How to load native libraries in tomcat farm?

Tags: java, tomcat

I read i.e. [How to add a native library in Tomcat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14018817/how-to-add-native-library-in-tomcat) and similar questions, but point is that this is not single Tomcat instance but some kind of shared tomcat running several instances. ('Tomcat farm' may be not correct name)

So structure I have in /data/tomcat-home/tomcat7-x-x/myapp:

bin/ (empty)

conf/ (catatlina.properties, server.xml, web.xml, ...)

lib/ (some jars)

logs/

webapps/ (ROOT/css, ROOT/WEB-INF)

I tried to put .so files to webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib, to lib/ -- but classloader cant find them: UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library: No suh file or directory

Answer (score 0):

Got it.

One of possible solutions is - create serverenv.sh in /bin directory and add there:
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$CATALINA_BASE/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH

put libraries to $CATALINA_BASE/lib