# Where is tomcat configuration in Cpanel?

Tags: tomcat, cpanel

I have tomcat 7 installed on a linux VPS under cPanel using easyapache 3.

It appears to be working - I can upload a war file and get my service to execute.

However, I need to make some configuration changes such as defining java.library.path.  There was an excellent description of that at [[How to add a native library in Tomcat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14018817/how-to-add-native-library-in-tomcat][1]).  It says to create a setenv.sh file in the configuration folder, which would also contains catalina.sh.

However, I cannot find any folder with catalina.sh on the cPanel server.  I have done a find on the entire file system, and it is just not there.  The only tomcat configuration files I can find are in a folder /usr/local/easy/etc/easy-tomcat7

```
drwxr-xr-x 3 root   nobody   4096 Sep  9 03:54 ./
drwxrwxr-x 3 root   wheel    4096 Jul 27 13:42 ../
drwxrwxr-x 4 root   nobody   4096 Sep  9 03:54 Catalina/
-rw-rw-r-- 1 tomcat nobody  11893 Jan 27  2015 catalina.policy
-rw-rw-r-- 1 tomcat nobody   5946 Jan 27  2015 catalina.properties
-rw-rw-r-- 1 tomcat nobody   1394 Jan 27  2015 context.xml
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root   nobody    144 Jan 27  2015 easy-tomcat7-chkserv
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root     5018 Sep  4 23:00 httpd-jk.conf
-rw-rw-r-- 1 tomcat nobody    547 Jan 27  2015 log4j.properties
-rw-rw-r-- 1 tomcat nobody   3288 Jan 27  2015 logging.properties
-rw-rw-r-- 1 tomcat nobody   6868 Sep  4 23:04 server.xml
-rw------- 1 tomcat nobody   2082 Sep  3 21:59 tomcat-users.xml
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root     1357 Sep  4 23:00 uriworkermap.properties
-rw-rw-r-- 1 tomcat nobody 162905 Jan 27  2015 web.xml
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root     6549 Sep  4 23:00 workers.properties
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root     1311 Sep  4 23:00 workers.properties.minimal
```

There are various configuration settings in server.xml, web.xml, catalina.policy, and catalina.properties but nothing matches up with what I see in catalina.sh(or bat) in my local development environment (Windows Tomcat 7).

Is there something special about how cPanel does the install?  And where might I put a setenv.bat file?  Or does it need to be done some other way?

I do have root access, and don't seem to have any trouble finding anything else on the server.

Thanks for any explanation of what might be going on here.

Comment: You should ask this question on: https://forums.cpanel.net/

Answer (score 0):

After way too many hours of searching I finally found the answer at 
https://forums.cpanel.net/threads/cpanel-tomcat-jsp-and-servlets-guide.282922/

**Java startup values**

If you wish to change startup values for Heap size and others (you can see the settings that are configurable if you issue “java -X” without the quotes), then a file named /var/cpanel/tomcat.options could be created.

Here’s an example of entries that could be placed into the file:

```
-Xmx200M
-Xms100M
```

And it works!