# How to load a dll and call a JNI method in Tomcat?

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, dll, java-native-interface

I have successfully called a method contained in a dll from a Java program using JNI. This is what i do:

```
public class MyClass {
  static {
     System.load("C:/Users/pabloruiz/library.dll");
     System.loadLibrary("library"); // This works too if the dll is in the Java Build Path
  }

  public native void foo();

  public static void main(String[] args) {
     new MyClass().foo();  // invoke the native method
  }
}
```

Now I'm trying to do the same but in a web app with Tomcat. I have tried using absolute paths and relative paths, placing the dll in WEB-INF/lib, selecting it in Properties->Java Build Path but it doesn't work. By the way, I'm working on Eclipse.

This is the error I get:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.example.MyClass.foo()
```

EDIT:

Apparently, it founds the dll because if I change the name to something that doesn't exist I get an error telling me that the dll couldn't be found. From what I understand it can't find the method foo() inside the dll, which is weird because, as I said above, that same dll works from a simple java program (not a web app).

Comment: Unsuccesful because it is unable to refer to path? or it could refer to path but couldn't load? Can you show the error

Comment: I've added the error I get

Comment: @PabloRP Where in Java Build Path did you try to add it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150428/native-libraries-not-found-in-tomcat