# Tess4j issue java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: java, ocr

I'm trying to solve the Tess4J installing problem ,
1 I had created a folder in WEB-INF\win32-x86
2 and I putted there the libtesseract302.dll and liblept168.dll and I add it to source/native library in the java build path 
when I run I found the error

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'libtesseract302': Native library (win32-x86/libtesseract302.dll) not found in resource path ([file:/C:/Program%20Files/Apache%20Software%20Foundation/Tomcat%207.0/wtpwebapps/OCR/WEB-INF/classes/, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Apache%20Software%20Foundation/Tomcat%207.0/wtpwebapps/OCR/WEB-INF/lib/ghost4j-0.5.1.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Apache%20Software%20Foundation/Tomcat%207.0/wtpwebapps/OCR/WEB-INF/lib/jai_imageio.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Apache%20Software%20Foundation/Tomcat%207.0/wtpwebapps/OCR/WEB-INF/lib/jna-4.1.0.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Apache%20Software%20Foundation/Tomcat%207.0/wtpwebapps/OCR/WEB-INF/lib/junit-4.10.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Apache%20Software%20Foundation/Tomcat%207.0/wtpwebapps/OCR/WEB-INF/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Apache%20Software%20Foundation/Tomcat%207.0/wtpwebapps/OCR/WEB-INF/lib/tess4j.jar])
com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(NativeLibrary.java:271)
com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getInstance(NativeLibrary.java:398)
com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.<init>(Library.java:147)
com.sun.jna.Native.loadLibrary(Native.java:412)
com.sun.jna.Native.loadLibrary(Native.java:391)
net.sourceforge.tess4j.TessAPI.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.init(Unknown Source)
net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Unknown Source)
net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Unknown Source)
net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Unknown Source)
ocrTest.doGet(ocrTest.java:39)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

**Note** I had checked that I'm using 32 jvm with

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("sun.arch.data.model"));
```

so I'm sure
**Questions**
how to fix this error ?
if I made an error in setup tess4j please tell me how ?

Comment: Try setting the appropriate variable as indicated in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14018817/how-to-add-native-library-in-tomcat and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150428/native-libraries-not-found-in-tomcat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution
**1** download `tesseract-ocr-setup-3.02.02.exe` from [here][1]  and install it
[1]: https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/downloads/list
**2** add this dependencies `ghost4j-0.5.1.jar`,`jai_imageio.jar`,`jna-4.1.0.jar` and `tess4j.jar` to project the build path
and Enjoy ;)

Comment: I dont your step advice, but get this error? 
Exception in thread main java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:Thespecified module could not be found.

 at com.sun.jna.Native.open(Native Method)
 at com.sun.jna.Native.open(Native.java:1759)
 at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(NativeLibrary.java:260)
 at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getInstance(NativeLibrary.java:398)
 at com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.<init>(Library.java:147)
 at com.sun.jna.Native.loadLibrary(Native.java:412)
 at com.sun.jna.Native.loadLibrary(Native.java:391)
 at net.sourceforge.tess4j.util.LoadLibs.getTessAPIInstance(Unknown Source)

Comment: at net.sourceforge.tess4j.TessAPI.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
 at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.init(Unknown Source)
 at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Unknown Source)
 at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Unknown Source)
 at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Unknown Source)
 at net.sourceforge.tess4j.example.TesseractExample.main(TesseractExample.java:14)

Comment: ****I've tried on both 64, and 32 bit same test source, from their site http://tess4j.sourceforge.net/codesample.html

Comment: @K.Ariche  your link is broken