# Unsatisfied Link Error while using Tesseract for OCR evaluation

Tags: java, dll, ocr, tesseract

Folks,

I'm trying out tesseract library for OCR evaluation.

I'm using Mac OS Yosemite. I've the project setup ready in eclipse, with the libtesseract302.dll in the build path. But when I run the main class, it throws me an error

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'libtesseract302': Native library (win32-x86/libtesseract302.dll) not found in resource path 
.....
.....
net.sourceforge.tess4j.TessAPI.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.init(Unknown Source)
net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Unknown Source)
net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Unknown Source)
net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Unknown Source)
ocrTest.doGet(ocrTest.java:39)
```

FYI -

I've already performed some tests to fix this issue following the steps as specified here, but it still throws me an error.

- [Tess4j issue java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24184763/tess4j-issue-java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror)
- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/tesseract-ocr/y8m_IIk767s
- [Tess4j unsatisfied link error on mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21394537/tess4j-unsatisfied-link-error-on-mac-os-x)

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a windows dll file on Mac OS X. Because your Java project requires native code, you may not be able to run it on a Mac at all. If you can get a `libtesseract302.dylib` (Mach-O Dynamic Library) then you could add that and it should work.

Comment: I'm not able to find that file for MacOS. Can you please share the link for that file ?

Comment: @peeppeep *you may not be able to run it on a Mac at all* or using  [homebrew](http://brew.sh/), `brew install tesseract` and then you should have it.

Comment: Using homebrew, i got this error `Error: You must `brew link jpeg libtiff libpng leptonica' before tesseract can be installed`